# Keras Conv1D input for a very large number of samples

Tags: python, keras, reshape, conv1d

I have a dataset containing a huge amount of samples 1686663 and 107 features (1686663, 107). I'm building a neural network using keras, and wanted to apply a 1D convolution Conv1D.

The input for the Conv1D is (batch size, number_features, timestep). the batch size is basically the number of samples, however in my case i cannot use the number of samples which is too large for my RAM. So i selected a batch size = 512.

```
in_shape = (batch_size,x_train.shape[1],1)
```

Hence, my input shape is now (512, 107, 1).

I reshaped the training vectors to match the convolution :

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0],x_train_shape[1],1)
```

When running training i get the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_10" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 512, 107, 1), found shape=(None, 107, 1)
```

Could anyone tell me what I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify the input shape, either by adding a [`tf.keras.Input`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Input) layer as first layer, or by setting the argument `input_shape` directly in the first layer of your model, you don't have to add the batch size. So in your case it would be:

```
in_shape = (x_train.shape[1], 1)
```

The batch size is ***automatically*** set as first dimension of your input shape, by taking the value you set in the `batch_size` argument of the [`fit()`](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/#fit-method) method.

But if you do like this `(batch_size, x_train.shape[1], 1)`, it will add the batch size twice.

The error is basically saying that it expected to find `(batch size, 512, 107, 1)` but found `(batch size, 107, 1)`. It was expecting that additional 512, because you added the batch size twice.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer, i figured it out juste fter posting the question. As you said i wanted to set the batch size manually, and this generated an extra dimension in the tensor. Thanks again.